# glDrawBuffers in opengl es 2.0 c++

Tags: c++, opengl-es

I'm porting code from Windows to Android and a few GL methods do not exist in Opengl ES 2.0.

The purpose is to render all to a texture that will be rendered using a specific shader for effects.

First line:

Windows version

```
glFramebufferTexture(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, renderedTexture, 0);
```

ES 2.0 version? I'm not sure

```
glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, renderedTexture, 0, 0);
```

second line:

windows version

```
GLenum DrawBuffers[1] = { GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0 };
glDrawBuffers(1, DrawBuffers);
```

ES 2.0 version ?

**missing**

code:

```
glGenFramebuffers(1, &FramebufferName);
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, FramebufferName);

glGenTextures(1, &renderedTexture);

glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, renderedTexture);

glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, 1024, 768, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 0);

glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);

glFramebufferTexture(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, renderedTexture, 0);

GLenum DrawBuffers[1] = { GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0 };
glDrawBuffers(1, DrawBuffers);
```

**EDIT:**

after adjustment the app runs but it crashes and logcat says:

```
D/libGLESv2: DTS_GLAPI : DTS is not allowed for Package : xxx.xxx
```

and the statement:

```
if (glCheckFramebufferStatus(GL_FRAMEBUFFER) != GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE)
```

is true

the current code is:

```
glGenFramebuffers(1, &FramebufferName);
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, FramebufferName);

glGenTextures(1, &renderedTexture);

glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, renderedTexture);

glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, 1024, 768, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 0);

glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);

glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, renderedTexture, 0, 0);
```

Comment: @Rabbid76: You are right. Sorry, my fault.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of [`glFramebufferTexture`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glFramebufferTexture.xhtml) in (desktop) OpenGL, it can be used [`glFramebufferTexture2D`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/es3/html/glFramebufferTexture2D.xhtml) in OpenGL ES 2.0.
The 3rd parameter of `glFramebufferTexture2D` is the texture target, which is `GL_TEXTURE_2D` in your case:

<s>`glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, renderedTexture, 0, 0);`</s>

```cpp
glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, 
                       GL_TEXTURE_2D, renderedTexture, 0);
```

Porting the call to [`glDrawBuffers`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/es3.0/html/glDrawBuffers.xhtml) is not necessary, since in the initial state the draw buffer for fragment color zero is `COLOR_ATTACHMENT0` and in OpenGL ES 2.0 the only possible color attachment is `COLOR_ATTACHMENT0`.
In OpenGL ES 3.0 this behavior changes and is similar the (desktop) OpenGL version which you are using.

Further note, to fulfill the rules of framebuffer completeness, the internal format of the attached image, has to be a *Color-renderable* format.

For a detailed information see [OpenGL ES 2.0 Full Specification](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/es/2.0/es_full_spec_2.0.pdf) - 4.4.5 Framebuffer Completeness (page 117/118).

> The framebuffer object target is said to be framebuffer complete if it is the
>   window-system-provided framebuffer, or if all the following conditons are true:
>
> [...]
>
> - The combination of internal formats of the attached images does not violate an implementation-dependent set of restrictions.

Comment: thank you,
now when i run it the app crash and logcat says:
02-22 13:47:39.194 23484-23574/xxx.xxx D/libGLESv2: DTS_GLAPI : DTS is not allowed for Package : xxx.xxx

and the statement if (glCheckFramebufferStatus(GL_FRAMEBUFFER) != GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE)
is true
any idea how to solve it?

Comment: It is not true that only GL_RGBA4, GL_RGB_A1 and GL_RGB565 are supported. First none of those are textures formats, those are renderbuffer formats only and therefore would make glFramebufferTexture2D useless. The spec says which texture formats are renderable is implementation dependent, section 4.4.5 page 118 "The combination of internal formats of the attached images does not violate
an implementation-dependent set of restrictions"  Pretty much all drivers support rendering to an RGBA/UNSIGNED_BYTE texture

Comment: @gman Indeed, of course you're right. Thank you for pointing that out. So there is no internal (renderable texture) format which is guaranteed to be supported on any hardware which supports OpenGL ES 2.0?

Comment: Correct, there is no format (renderbuffer or texture) that is guaranteed to be renderable by the spec. In reality I know of no implementations that don't support RGBA/UNSIGNED_BYTE. It's not until ES 3.0 that added required combinations